# Loading photo using FileProvider causing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-fileprovider

I want to use `FileProvider` to obtain photo from camera. I did everything from this tutorial, but `authority` parameter causing error.

Tutorial: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Provider inside `AndroidManifest`:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

`provider_paths.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is create file function:

```
private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()
        ).format(Date())
        val imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_"
        val image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            null      /* directory */
        )

        return image
    }
```

This is `provider_paths.xml` (I dont want external path because I dont want from user to accept storage permissions to use camera) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name = "name"
        path = "path" />
</paths>
```

This is open camera function:

```
private fun openCamera() {
        val tempFile = createImageFile()
        photoUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile)
        photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(a, a.applicationContext.packageName + ".fileprovider", tempFile)

        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(a.packageManager) != null) {
            a.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA_NODE_MISUSE)
        }
    }
```

Error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/my.package.name/cache/IMG_20190620_102915_7513574861671405500.jpg`

Comment: add manifest file too here

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put your file provider in the manifest as well inside  `application` tag

```
<application
            ...>
     ....
    <provider
            android:authorities = "your_string"
            android:name = "androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported = "false"
            android:grantUriPermissions = "true">
        <meta-data
                android:resource = "@xml/file_path"
                android:name = "android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

And my `file_path.xml` is like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
            name = "my_images"
            path = "Android/data/com.your.package/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

And from the java code

```
val authorities = "your_string"

val imageUri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
     FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!, authorities, imageFile)
else
     Uri.fromFile(imageFile)

callCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
            startActivityForResult(
                callCameraIntent,
                CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE
            )
```

**Update**

your file provider authorities in the manifest and your authorities in your code should match.
Your problem is your `authorities` is different in manifest and java code

```
`android:authorities = "${applicationId}.fileprovider"`
```

in your java code replace this

```
photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(a, a.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", tempFile)
```

to this

```
photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(a, a.applicationContext.packageName + ".fileprovider", tempFile)
```

**Second Update**

In this function you are passing to the directory which should not be the case:

```
private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()
        ).format(Date())
        val imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_"
        val image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            null      /* directory */
        )

        return image
    }
```

Try this

```
private fun createImageFile(): File {
            val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()
            ).format(Date())
            val imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_"
            val image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName, /* prefix */
                ".jpg", /* suffix */
                context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) //null /* directory */
            )

            return image
        }
```

Comment: Tried your, doesnt work. Same exception. My file_path.xml is from tutorial aswell.

Comment: I have found your error have a look my updated anser

Comment: I've seen this before and replaced that, but it doesnt work after update

Comment: Post your full code, manifest, provider_paths, and java code, then maybe I can detect your error

Comment: In this function you are passing to the directory which should not be the case: See my answer

Comment: Used your directory solution and still same exception. I really don't know what is wrong. Checked 4 different tutorials for FireProvider and my code is exactly the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195255/discussion-between-jasurbek-and-martin1337).